# Run two functions that contain while loops at the same time in Python using multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to run two functions at the same time in Python. Both functions contain `while` loops. I have tried to use threading and multiprocessing with no joy. Only one function runs. I have read and tried several examples on Stack and net. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I am new to Python.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-c", "--conf", required=True,
       help="path to the JSON configuration file")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
#    p1 = Process(target=main(args))
#    p2 = Process(target=cameraHandler(args))
#    p1.start()
#    p2.start()

    threadA = Thread(target = main(args))
    threadB = Thread(target = cameraHandler(args))
    threadA.run()
    threadB.run()

    threadA.join()
    threadB.join()
```

Comment: To truly run functions "at the same time" you need to use `multiprocessing`. Also, I hope you realize that `//` is not a comment in Python... you want `#`

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga  That is a great answer , well done!! And, as you know it all it can be achieved using multi-threading. Also, i know ## is a comment in Python. Great answer doh, you obviously know a lot ! Why didn't you give a solution to the question instead of a negative comment ?

Comment: I was merely asking for clarification, because you say you want two run two functions *at the same time*, and in CPython, this is not possible using `multithreading`, since the GIL ensures that only one thread runs in the interpreter at once. If you truly want to take advantage of a multicore architecture, and run things in parallel, you must use `multiprocessing`. The API is very similar, so if that is actually a concern for you, you should be able to convert your code easily. I did not downvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you have `target = main(args)` and `target = cameraHandler(args)`. In both of these cases, you are calling the function itself, rather than leaving the thread to do so. Thus, only the first is called, and `threadA` is never even created. You should be passing the functions themselves (`main` and `cameraHandler`) to `Thread`, *without* calling them.

To fix this, use the `args` keyword argument for `Thread`. You should also be using the `.start()` method of `Thread`.

```
Thread(target=main, args=(args,)).start()
Thread(target=cameraHandler, args=(args,)).start()
```

This is assuming `args` is a single argument you would like to pass to each of the functions. If it is a tuple of *all* the arguments you would like to pass, use `args=args`. For example, if you would like the thread to run `f(1, 2, 3)`, use `Thread(target=f, args=(1, 2, 3))`.

Comment: shouldn't the threads be deamons? If I recall correctly python will wait for the thread to finish before continuing if the thread isn't a deamon

Comment: @OwainvanBrakel According to my testing, this works without daemonizing the threads. :)

Comment: I did not expect that... Thanks for answering!

Comment: Thank you so much Harrison Grodin, much appreciated :) It worked

Comment: @Wazzi Fantastic! To show future people with the same issue that this solution worked, feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer. :)